# Why referential integrity constraints are not working in my code? How do I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I have made dno as my primary key in departmentdum1 table ,and the dno in sigdum14 is referencing to departmentdum1 table dno attribute .I should get the error when I execute this code because I'm trying to put dno value as 5 in sigdum14 table which should show error but it is not showing

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('Form.db')
print("connected")
conn.execute('create table departmentdum1 (d_name varchar(20),dno int 
primary key)') 
print("created");
conn.execute('insert into departmentdum1 values("computer science",1)')
print("execute");
conn.execute('insert into departmentdum1 values("Information 
science",2)')
print("execute");

conn.execute('create table sigdum14 ( y_name varchar(20),dno integer, 
foreign key(dno) REFERENCES departmentdum1(dno))') ;
print("created");
conn.execute('insert into sigdum14 values("kim",5)')
print("execute");



print("desc done");
conn.commit();
```

connected
created
execute
execute
created
execute
desc done

The output is wrong!!

Comment: Your code doesn't verify that the SQL commands to create create the foreign-key constraint actually succeeds. It's possible that it's failing.

Comment: What happens if you browse the database file using a SQLite GUI that shows the structure and constraints?

Answer (score 2):

sqlite doesn't enforce foreign key constraints by default. However, you can change this behavior by adding this line:

```
conn.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1")
```

just after opening your connection.

For more details, see [chapter 2](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) of the doc:

> In order to use foreign key constraints in SQLite, the library must be compiled with neither `SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY` or `SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER` defined. [...]
>
> Assuming the library is compiled with foreign key constraints enabled, it **must still be enabled by the application at runtime**, using the `PRAGMA foreign_keys` command.